# Regex to match "or" but not "for"

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm using a macro in excel to sort through sentence strings in a particular column.

I want to be able to select with a regex `or` but not `for`.

So far, the regex is pulling out everything with the two letters `or` in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
\bor\b
```

If you're looking for the word `or` specifically, or:

```
(?<!\bf)or
```

if you want to match all `or` except the word `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word boundary `\b`:

```
(^|\b)or(\b|$)
```